# Python: Add on/off functionality in the function with button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-multithreading, plotly-dash

I have written a small multithreaded program which appends a list to a pandas dataframe in an elementwise fashion, this append function runs on a separate thread and appends an element from the list to the  dataframe every two seconds, the second function which is called check_signal() runs in a while loop on main thread and uses a generator to output a specific signal based on the value of the element of the dataframe. The threshold values of this generator can be configured in the script.

I want to add the functionality in program that the user can start and stop the check_signal() function and change/modify the threshold , I plan to do it from GUI like plotly Dash , I have written the buttons etc but I am not able to wrap my head around the logic, anyone please help:

Working Code , please copy paste to run on your system:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import time 
import threading 


##############################
##############################
# This is to simulate data coming from a websocket , external stream etc.
##############################
##############################

# Define threading lock 
lock = threading.Lock()


# Define list of random numbers , can be very long 
a = [2,3,4,5,6,0,8,7,1,3,4,0,6,4,0,2,4,0,4,5,0,1,7,0,1,8,5,3,6,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,2,0.5,-1,-2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,8,6,5,3,4,5]

# Define Empty DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['pct_diff'])


# Create the function to append to 
def append_to_frame():
    global df
    for i in a :
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'pct_diff' : [i]}))
        #print(df['pct_diff'][-1])
        time.sleep(2)
# Run function on thread 
t_1 = threading.Thread(target=append_to_frame, args=(), daemon=True)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


##############################
##############################
# This part we define our generator and check signal function,
# this is wehere I want to add the switch on/off functionality 
##############################
##############################

# Define generator which will generate signal based on upper threshold ut and 
# lower threshold lt
def signal(ut, lt):
    current_state = "Outside market"

    while True:
        pct_change = yield current_state

        if (
            current_state in ("Outside market", "Market exit")
            and pct_change >= ut
        ):
            current_state = "Entered market"
        elif current_state == "Entered market" and pct_change > lt:
            current_state = "Inside market"
        elif current_state == "Market exit" and pct_change < ut:
            current_state = "Outside market"
        elif (
            current_state in ("Entered market", "Inside market")
            and pct_change < lt
        ):
            current_state = "Market exit"

# Instantiate generator with parameters
s = signal(5,2) # Configure upper and lower threshold 
next(s)

# Define check signal function 
def check_signal():
    while True:
        signal = s.send(df['pct_diff'].iloc[-1])
        print("Percent Diff : {}, Sgnal : {}".format(df['pct_diff'].iloc[-1], signal))
        time.sleep(3)


# Start append function on thread 
with lock:
    t_1.start()

# Start check signal in while loop 
check_signal()
```

Comment: Seems to me that you want to control the `True` part of `while True:`. Create some global variable, e.g. `toggle = True` which you can flip by the press of your button, use it to control your while-loop in `check_signal()`: `while toggle:`

Comment: Hi, @plasma , I wanted to ask one more thing, what if I want to change the values for the generator as well , I mean the upper and lower threshold, is there a way to reinitialise the generator as well?